# reliability of Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule

Tags: android, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

Is there some known issue with this executor? Or am I using it wrong way? I need to schedule uploads **in separate thread** and I want the next upload to fire after a certain time after current upload had finished.

So there are some code excerpts from my Service implementation:

```
ScheduledExecutorService periodicUploadExecutor;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // some stuff...

    periodicUploadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    periodicUploadExecutor.schedule(uploadPointsToServer, getCurrentUploadIntervalInMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private Runnable uploadPointsToServer = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Log.d("SOMETAG", "--->>>  UPLOAD runnable started!");

        // upload stuff here...

        Log.d("SOMETAG", " upload runnable scheduling next after "+getCurrentUploadIntervalInMs());
        periodicUploadExecutor.schedule(uploadPointsToServer, getCurrentUploadIntervalInMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Log.d("SOMETAG", "<<<---  upload runnable ENDED!");
    }
}

private final int getCurrentActiveSampIntervalInMs() {
    return 300000; // just an example
}
```

But as I examine the logs I see the following:

```
01-08 15:33:42.166 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): --->>>  UPLOAD runnable started!
01-08 15:33:43.166 D/SOMETAG ( 4606):  upload runnable scheduling next after 300000
01-08 15:33:43.166 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): <<<---  upload runnable ENDED!
01-08 15:38:43.166 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): --->>>  UPLOAD runnable started!
01-08 15:38:44.174 D/SOMETAG ( 4606):  upload runnable scheduling next after 300000
01-08 15:38:44.174 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): <<<---  upload runnable ENDED!
01-08 15:43:44.174 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): --->>>  UPLOAD runnable started!
01-08 15:43:45.143 D/SOMETAG ( 4606):  upload runnable scheduling next after 300000
01-08 15:43:45.143 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): <<<---  upload runnable ENDED!
01-08 16:01:38.887 D/SOMETAG ( 4606): --->>>  UPLOAD runnable started!
```

So first three go well but the last one starts after eighteen minutes, not five! This service also gets location updates between 15:43 and 16:01, but location listener operates on main thread and there are few seconds long periods between location updates so nothing should block  scheduled executor to fire... but it **is** late by more than three times the scheduled delay! How's that possible?

Comment: if you are scheduling, so far apart, you should rather use AlarmManager. Usually service might get stopped in the middle and if Cpu is in sleep mode, scheduler wont wake up the cpu, but alarmManager will

Comment: What surprises me is that 2nd runnable doesn't wait for 3 minutes before starting

Comment: @fiddler 300000ms is five minutes, as you see in the logs evety runnable of the first three starts 5 minutes after the previous finishes

Comment: @nandeesh thanks for your remark i will take look into it. But in this particular case the service is not stopped, there are location manager updates going on in main thread (i removed them from logs for clarity)

Comment: is the phone display off during this time. if the phone display is off, that mostly means , it is asleep. During this time no job can be scheduled. You need wakelocks if you need to schedule jobs without phone going to sleep mode

Comment: @nandeesh I will check this but there is nothing about it in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html ... does this apply to all devices or is it device-specific?

Comment: this applies to all devices, if the phone is in sleep mode, it will not do any job , try acquiring a [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and run the same app again, but you should be really careful about using these, battery will run out easily if you acquire for too much time. That is why alarmManager is better

Comment: or just to try, keep the display timeout to maximum and try again, if it is working in display on case, then it is definitely related to sleep mode

Comment: @nandeesh hey, thanks, partial wake lock helps a lot! Display goes to sleep but CPU is active, so no more time gaps! If you wish you can post official answer ad I will mark it as accepted. BTW: is alarmManager the only scheduling method that works in background without wakeLocks? How about Handler postDelayer and similar stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AlarmManager` instead of Executor/handler or use a Partial [Wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to keep the cpu on.

If cpu is in sleep mode, your app will not run until phone wakes up.
AFAIK only `AlarmManager` can get you a callback by waking up the device. For this you need to use either  `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` or `RTC_WAKEUP` type, other options will again result in delay.